# Metamask not connected with web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask, infura

```
   if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
       window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/api_key"));
    }
     web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x37273441D1ecac689220bE6934Cfb8b8B1e85Ca9";
     var StudentContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant": false, "inputs": [{"name": "Key", "type": "bytes32"}, {"name": "Rollno", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "Name", "type": "string"}, {"name": "Age", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "Branch", "type": "string"}, {"name": "Internal_marks", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "External_marks", "type": "uint256"} ], "name": "StoreDocument", "outputs": [{"name": "success", "type": "bool"} ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"constant": true, "inputs": [{"name": "", "type": "bytes32"} ], "name": "document", "outputs": [{"name": "Rollno", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "Name", "type": "string"}, {"name": "Age", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "Branch", "type": "string"}, {"name": "Internal_marks", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "External_marks", "type": "uint256"}, {"name": "Internalstatus", "type": "string"}, {"name": "Externalstatus", "type": "string"} ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"} ]);
     var Student = StudentContract.at('0x93D030A5e74d8d5e142DF5d3e974dDF8CF1cf3D3');
     console.log(Student);
     $("#button").click(function() {
     var key = $('#key').val();
  var roll_number = $('#roll_number').val();
 var name = $('#name').val();
 var age = $('#age').val();
 var branch = $('#branch').val();
 var internal_marks = $('#inter').val();
 var external_marks = $('#exter').val();
     Student.StoreDocument( key, roll_number, name, age, branch, internal_marks, external_marks, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas:3000000});
    console.log(Student);
});
```

Comment: please provide detail about the error not just a title and the code. What did you try what did you do? Metamask version if it is metamask problem then maybe you can post it on the issue on metamask github

Comment: Uncaught Error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available when I submit the data on Ropsten Testnet. Another button is working properly.

Comment: @Hacker001  ```Student.StoreDocument( key, roll_number, name, age, branch, internal_marks, external_marks, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas:3000000});
    console.log(Student); ``` This method is not supported.Try by sending transactions using web3.eth.sendTransaction.

Comment: @CrissiMariamRobert Please tell me web3.eth.sendTransaction is used within Stuent.document or used in outside in function.

Comment: @Hacker001 Create a separate function outside Student.document.Can use both sendTransaction & sendRawTransaction